# TRY_CAST conversion issue

Tags: sql-server

I'm facing a weird issue. It would be great if some one help me on this. This query worked like a charm until i add `where` clause with `IS NULL` . If i execute with `Is null` i got below error (With `IS not Null` query is working fine).

When i execute the inner query i got the desired result set invalid records with null values and Valid records has been casts properly. But when i try to filter it in outer query it fails that too because of few records.

Doubts: In inner query all invalid records has been converted to `null` i could see that. But why it fails when it comes to outer query that too only because of few records (i found this by executing invalid records one by one)?

Is that issue with `Try_cast`?

```
select Number,content from (
    select Name, Number,
    TRY_cast( 
      TRY_CAST(
        TRY_CAST(
          (Content) AS VARBINARY (MAX)
        ) AS XML
      ) as nvarchar (max)
    ) as content 
    from Documents 
    where LTRIM(RTRIM(NAME)) in ('XYZ.xmll')
) A 
where Content is null
```

> Error: Warning: Fatal error 7102 occurred at Jun 7 2016 4:47PM. Note the error and time, and contact your system administrator.

Comment: Wow - cool! Looks like you blew up SQL server. There's no problem with the syntax.

Comment: What's with all the nested `TRY_CAST`? Why do you even need `TRY_CAST`? Doesn't a simple `CAST(Content AS NVARCHAR(MAX))` work? What's the type of `content`?

Comment: Does look a touch convoluted

Comment: Error 7102 should not occur (it's an internal error), but then you do have a rather bizarre query here. Just to be sure, though, run `DBCC CHECKTABLE('documents')` to make sure the internal structures are OK. If this returns no error, you've found an issue that may warrant a bug report on Connect.